# How to set UVs of a quad containing a non-square and non-power-of-two RenderTexture?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to render something manually using APIs like `Graphics.DrawMeshNow()`.

Now I need to draw a `RenderTexture` using a quad mesh. This `RenderTexture` is non-square and non-power-of-two, for example 1901 x 995.

I don't know how to set the UVs for the quad in this situation.

Will this kind of texture internally be padded to 2048 x 2048?

Do I need to calculate the relative position of the real content in the padded texture, using (0,0), (1901/2048, 0), (1901/2048, 995/2048), (0, 995/2048) as the quad's UV?

Or should I ignore this kind of thing and just set UVs to (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1)?

Or is this a more complex thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ignore this kind of thing and just set UVs to (0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (0,1).